# How to unit test firebase auth in a NextJS app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, jestjs, firebase-authentication

I am trying to setup and unit test `firebase auth` in a Next JS project.
Setup:
`package.json`

```
"firebase": "^9.6.10",
"firebase-admin": "^10.0.2",
"next": "12.1.1",
```

I want to unit test the parts of the code where there is conditional rendering based on if user is logged in.

Firebase does not seem to have much resources for [unit testing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests) for authentication.

Error:

```
    FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).

      25 |     }
      26 |
    > 27 |     return firebaseClient.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
         |                           ^
      28 |       if (!user) {
      29 |         setUser(null);
      30 |         nookies.set(undefined, 'token', '', { path: '/' });
      


  ● Console

    console.error
      Error: Uncaught [FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).]
      ...
      {
        code: 'auth/invalid-api-key',
        customData: { appName: '[DEFAULT]' }
      }

      at VirtualConsole.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29:45)
      at reportException (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:70:28)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:341:9)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)

    console.error
      The above error occurred in the <AuthProvider> component:
```

Here is `AuthProvider.tsx` that wraps around the entire app.

```
     
type AuthProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};
type User = firebaseClient.User;

const AuthContext = createContext<{ user: User | null }>({
  user: null,
});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps): JSX.Element => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);

  // handle auth logic here...

  // listen for token changes
  // call setUser and write new token as a cookie
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      (window as any).nookies = nookies;
    }

    return firebaseClient.auth().onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
      if (!user) {
        setUser(null);
        nookies.set(undefined, 'token', '', { path: '/' });
      } else {
        const token = await user.getIdToken();
        setUser(user);
        nookies.set(undefined, 'token', token, { path: '/' });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  // force refresh the token every 10 minutes
  useEffect(() => {
    const handle = setInterval(async () => {
      const user = firebaseClient.auth().currentUser;
      if (user) await user.getIdToken(true);
    }, 10 * 60 * 1000);

    // clean up setInterval
    return () => clearInterval(handle);
  }, []);
  return <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

Here is the provider wrapping around the children elements in `_app.tsx`

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Header />
      <MainLayout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </MainLayout>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Here is an example of the test setup that depends on the user has been logged in or not.

```
  test('if it has a logout button', () => {
    render(<Sidebar />);
    const logoutButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /logout/i });
    expect(logoutButton).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Code that depends on the user state that is logged in.

`header.tsx`

```
import { useAuth } from '@/store/auth';

export const Header = () => {
const { user } = useAuth();
return (
  <header className="bg-menubar text-primary-text">
    <nav>{user ? <Sidebar /> : <h1>Not logged In</h1>}</nav>
  </header>
);
};
```

Here is a `test-util.tsx`

```
import { render, RenderOptions } from '@testing-library/react';
import { FC, ReactElement } from 'react';

import { AuthProvider } from '@/store/auth';

const AllTheProviders: FC = ({ children }) => {
  return <AuthProvider>{children}</AuthProvider>;
};

const customRender = (ui: ReactElement, options?: Omit<RenderOptions, 'wrapper'>) =>
  render(ui, { wrapper: AllTheProviders, ...options });

export * from '@testing-library/react';
export { customRender as render };
```

I can confirm that the Keys are correct and it does work on local and allows me to sign in.